# C++ Singleton in multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am new to multi thread programming, yet I am studying a big project by someone else. In the code he has a singleton class and it has some public member variable and a member mutex. He used this singleton in different threads like:

```
singleton::instance()->mutex.lock();
singleton::instance()->value = getval();
singleton::instance()->mutex.release();
```

Is this the safe way to do it? 
If not what is the proper way of read/write the value in singleton?

Comment: Could you please show the singleton code, too? It is nearly impossible to tell without that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not safe to do so.

The problem is that the mutex is handed out to the user. There is no guarantee that this lock will be released.  For example, what happens if `getval()` would throw an exception ?

The proper way to do so would be to embed mutex use inside the API of your singleton.  For example:

```
void singleton::setvalue(int val) {  // example supposing value is an int
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mylck (mutex);
    value = val; 
    }
```

In this example, a local [std::lock_guard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/lock_guard/) is used.  This object locks the mutex and unlocks it on destruction.  This makes sure that in any case the mutex will be unlocked, whenever function returns and even if an exception would be thrown.

Comment: disagree. if getval throws exception then the lock is never released, and the variable inside the instance will not get ruined so its still safe to do so. In that case he will have to deal with deadlock exception but its another story.

Comment: @Steve unfortunately when the thread who held the mutex suffers an exception, he doesn't know anymore if he hold the lock or if the lock is held by another thread.  Nobody knows who holds the lock and the lock is held forever.  That's the kind of desing one should avoid...

Answer (score 1):

Note: If all you are doing is getting a variable like `return variable;` then it is safe to do even without the lock.

About the code. Assuming the lock is implemented correctly then it is safe to do anything before release is called

Comment: you mean I can do sth like: double val = singleton::instance()->value without mutex?

Comment: @Nyaruko yes. But if you are doing something like ->GetValue() and inside the function it is doing calculation or some sorts then you MIGHT need to lock it

Comment: You can do this but you have no guarantee that the value you will read is consistant with your expectations (i.e. one thread may read one value, and another thread may read another value, and even you might read a value that was never assigned to the variable if your thread reads a result of an unfinished store !!! You can have a safe read without lock only if your value is `atomic<>`

Comment: @Christophe It is totally expected that different thread would get different values isn't it?? for variable that is never assigned to... whats wrong with null value?? We do null checks all the time. as for unfinished store, please name a case where a variable could be in such state.

Comment: The problem isn't different values. It is race conditions and hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's not totally expected, but as soon as you have more than one thread accessing to the variable, you might experience this. In a multicore version one core might start write at the same time than the other is reading.  You can also have different cached values.   This is why you cannot just read the variable and hope everything will be ok:  your code has to make sure that it will ! Either with a lock or with an atomic.

Comment: @juanchopanza race condition would only occur if one thread's read depends on another thread finishes writing. But that's just bad design. If its value++ then sure I would totally agree a lock is required, but if its pure read. Nope, in most cases lock is not needed at all

Comment: @Christophe you are getting multi core wrong then. even in multi core machine memory read/write is still atomic. So there is never going to be a case where a variable is in half written state. And plus it is the computer engineer or OS's job to make sure cache is consistent with current value. It is not our job. (Dirty bit is there for a reason)

Comment: At anyone interested in more details, I recommend part I video of Herb Sutter http://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/ which explains all this much better than my poor comments.